# Eval with Image Bind to GridView

Tags: asp.net, image, gridview

i'm using following code for displaying image inside gridview

```
  <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Contact" 
                    HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="left" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="left" >
                <HeaderTemplate>
                          Cover Image
                            </HeaderTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Image ID="imgCover" runat="server" AlternateText="Image Cover" ImageUrl='<%# Eval("Cover_Path") %>' />

                </ItemTemplate>
                <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Left"></HeaderStyle>
                <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Left"></ItemStyle>
            </asp:TemplateField>
```

in the bind data source to gridview "Cover_Path" value is

```
E:\Industry\BicesterBooks\BookCovers\sq.jpg
```

which is the full path tot he image come from the database table.
but the image is not displaying on the web page.can any one help plz?

Comment: image to be allways a virtual path not the physical path ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the virtual path worked for me.

~/BookCovers/sq.jpg

Answer (score 2):

Put your images inside your web project may be under some folder let us say images. And save the file name only with its extension in the database. Having this, let me assume you put your images in a subfolder images under the root folder of your website. Your ImageUrl should be put this way:

```
  ...
  <ItemTemplate>
   <asp:Image ID="imgCover" runat="server" AlternateText="Image Cover" ImageUrl='<%# Eval("Cover_Path","~/Images/{0}") %>' />
        .....
```